# Javascript modulo operation in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, modulo

For adding a class to every third item in a List I am using a modulo operation like this:

```
var projectElements = document.getElementById("projectList").children;
var iCount = 0;
for (var i in projectElements) {
    iCount++;
    if (iCount % 3 == 0) {
        if (projectElements[i].className == "") {
            projectElements[i].className += "projectLinkLast";
        }
        else {
            projectElements[i].className += " projectLinkLast";
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in Firefox and other browsers except for Internet Explorer 7.
Does anybody have a clue why?

Comment: modulo is not the problem, I believe it has to do with the class names adding. you might want to consider JQuery to add classes http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Whats the length of projectElements within IE7?

Comment: Send a link to live demo that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @jeromeG: Adding a class to an element is trivial without jQuery: `el.className += " foo"`. You can check for an empty `className` for tidiness if you like but it's not necessary. And that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the modulo operator that's the problem. The problem is probably your use of `for...in` over a host object (in this case, the `children` property of an element), which is a bad idea and not guaranteed to work as you expect (or indeed at all).  Also, `children` isn't supported in all browsers (although it is in IE 7, so that's not the problem in that browser). I would suggest the following instead:

```
var iCount = 0, child = document.getElementById("projectList").firstChild;
while (child) {
    if (child.nodeType == 1) { // Only deal with elements
        iCount++;
        if (iCount % 3 == 0) {
            if (child.className == "") {
                child.className = "projectLinkLast";
            }
            else {
                child.className += " projectLinkLast";
            }
        }
    }
    child = child.nextSibling;
}
```

Comment: You wrote childCount but meant iCount. After I replaced that it worked out fine!
Thank you very much, Tim Down.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `.setAttribute("className", "blah")` instead of the .className.

Got a demo of your code on JSFiddle and seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/LWsTn/6/

If you are gonna use jQuery. Use:

```
$("#projectList :nth-child(3n").addClass("projectLinkLast");
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

**The addClass method jQuery is using that might help**

```
classNames = value.split(rspace);

for (i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
    elem = this[i];

    if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
        if (!elem.className && classNames.length === 1) {
            elem.className = value;

        } else {
            setClass = " " + elem.className + " ";

            for (c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++) {
                if (!~setClass.indexOf(" " + classNames[c] + " ")) {
                    setClass += classNames[c] + " ";
                }
            }
            elem.className = jQuery.trim(setClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggesting changing to `setAttribute("className")` is really bad advice. The `className` property is rock-solid in all major browsers whereas `setAttribute("className")` will not work in anything except old versions of IE, which have a broken `setAttribute()` implementation that maps attributes to properties.

Comment: Good point, you are totally right, but if that setAttribute did work in his IE7, it would have been solved. Because then he was able to use both. Updated my post, with an example jQuery is using.